# expire_log_days parameter value not updated?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, binlog

I have one MySQL RDS and i am trying to change the expire_log_days parameter value, but i'm unable to change because it's unmodified parameter. But while i am checking inside database it shows 0, Please find the below screenshot for your reference.

[image]

[image]

Why expire_log_days shows 0, Can anyone clarify me why it's happened, and also i wnat to know both are same or different parameter, as per my understanding both the parameters are same only the time units different.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html says:

> If a non-zero value for one of the variables binlog_expire_logs_seconds or expire_logs_days is set at startup, this value is used as the binary log expiration period. If a non-zero value for both of those variables is set at startup, the value for binlog_expire_logs_seconds is used as the binary log expiration period, and the value for expire_logs_days is ignored with a warning message.

This means it's okay for `expire_logs_days` to be 0. MySQL will ignore it, and use the value of `binlog_expire_logs_seconds`.

There is no intention that one value updates the other automatically.

Comment: Currently it's 2592000 seconds which is 30 days, I need to change it to 7 days, But i am unable to modify that parameter group, how can i change to 7 days, Is it possible?

Comment: Sounds like a question for AWS technical support. You're supposed to be able to change it using a parameter group. If you can't, and you think you should have AWS privileges to modify the parameter group, then you need to ask them why.